# how tell if a series of power numbers is bigger then others

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I trying to order a list of mathematical expressions in string format as:

```
"2*2"
"4^1"
"4^2^5"
```

so far, so good for non exponential operations **(^)**. I could compute the final result.

Except for exponential operations, cos take tooo long to compute, e.g.: $100^{20^{10}}$

My question is:

How tell if :

$1oo^{40}$ is bigger than $2^{22^{20}}$ ?

p.s: without computing the expression.

EDIT

how I can scale in this case

$100^{20^{2^{2}}}$ < $10^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}}$ ??

Comment: These are not equations, I think.

Comment: There is no general rule. You just use some ingenuity, starting with obvious estimates. For example, $100^{40}=10^{80}$ we have $22^{20}>10^{20}$ we also have $2^{10}>10$, so $2^{22^{20}}$ is greater than $2^{10^{20}}$ is greater than $10^{10^{19}}$, which is vastly bigger than $10^{80}$.

Comment: If you run out of digits on your calculator, you can always make the number smaller by taking a log. Take the log of both sides and use the log-power rule

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici just corrected , thanks

Comment: @almagest I tried to apply log, so I could reduce the exponential terms but after the 3 application of log operation a constant appears: I will explain better: Take the number $2^{20^{2^{2}}}$ if I apply the $log$ three times will looks like that: first time : $20^{2} log 2$ second time: $2^{2}log(20)+log(log(2))$. Third time: $log(2^{2}log(20)+log(log(2)))$ I can't reduce $log(x+y)$

Comment: $100^{40}<(2^7)^{40}=2^{7*40}=2^{280}$ but $2^{22^{30}}>2^{22^{2}}=2^{484}$. Hence, $2^{22^{30}}>100^{40}$. If you are allowed to take the logarithm then Alvaro Joao's suggestion is the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, logarithms definitely make things look more comparable.

$$10^{40},2^{22^{20}}$$

$$40,22^{20}\log_{10}(2)$$

We can quickly see that $40<22^{20}$ and that $\log_{10}(2)>0.01$

From this it seems clear that $40<(0.01)22^{20}<22^{20}$.

Comment: Hey I liked your approach, how I can scale in this case $100^{20^{2^{2}}}$ > $10^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}}$ ??

Comment: @AlvaroJoao The key is to use inequalities that are more comparable.  For yours, take $\log_{10}$ of both sides to get $$2\cdot20^{4}=2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}$$ $$20<2^{2^{2^2}}\implies2\cdot20^4<2(2^{2^{2^2}})^4<2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}$$ It is more obvious that adding more $2$'s to the top will increase the number more than powering by $4$ and multiplying be $2$.  So the inequality is $$100^{20^4}<10^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be this:
Say you have $100^{40} $ and $2^{22^{20}}$, like you said. Take the log and ask, in this case, if
$$\frac {40\log 100}{22^{20}\log 2} = \frac {40}{22^{20}}\log_2 100 < 1?$$
Then just compute the powers until it's under 1 then stop, and try and with both ways switching which number you put on the numerator. This hold up until there's overflow, but it atleast reduces the chance of overflow compared to just trying to do raw computation of the numbers. Surely there is more optimization that can be done though.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text {(Part 1 )}\quad100^{40}<(2^7)^{40}=2^{280}<2^{22^{2^2}}.$$ $$\text {(Part 2) }\quad 100^{20^{2^2}}=10^{2\cdot 20^{2^2}}<10^{20\cdot 20^{2^2}} =10^{20^{(1+2^2)}}<10^{32\cdot 32^{2^2}}=10^{(2^5)^{(1+2^2)}}=$$ $$=10^{2^{5\cdot (1+2^2)}}=10^{2^{25}}<10^{2^{32}}=10 ^{2^{2^5}}$$ $$\text { which is less than }\quad 10^{2^{2^{16}}}=10^{2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}}.$$ It's usually best to work up from the bottom.